# How do I create a root link in wordpress to a PDF file?

Tags: customization, menus, redirect, links

I want to upload my resume to media (which I have done) but link it directly to

joeblow.com/resume

I want that link to display the PDF ideally or if not possible to redirect to a URL (the resume is in wp-content/uploads/...)

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're aware this site is for development and any answers you get will require technical knowledge? Some PHP knowledge required, as well as perhaps knowledge of how redirects or rewrite rules work depending on the solution chosen

Comment: I'm actually an old PHP developer but haven't used it in years. I can build a blog myself, but chose WordPress for convenience. Are you saying something as trivial as me wanting to publish a page or content directly to a named page is something WordPress has failed to integrate? it seems so basic! I'll do it in PHP if I have to, but dang I wasn't hoping it would get to that. Some buried menu feature I hadn't uncovered yet.

Comment: On second thought: PHP shouldn't even be necessary for something like this. It's a PDF. I just want wordpress to create a custom link for me, but when I enter "custom link" into google, it thinks I want to add a custom link to my menu. I want the NAME to be custom, NOT the link itself.

Comment: Menus are a distraction here that have nothing to do with what you're trying to do, you can have it load the PDF and display it or do a redirect, and there are plugins that can do that ( recommendations are offtopic here ), but a page is a post of type `page`, to give a PDF a new URL is a nonsensical sentence when taken literally in the WP world. Redirects would yield far better research than custom names ( aka slugs/permalinks )

Comment: I should note as well, that you'll get a technical answer here because this is WordPress Development, a Q&A site for developers. The general support forums might be more useful if you're looking for user support

Comment: I'd probably just opt for a custom `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` (or equivalent) - mostly because it would take me a couple minutes to set up as opposed to wading through WordPress's rewrite rule interfaces.

Comment: thanks guys, i'll try the .htaccess Rewrite seems i'll just upload current resume to resume.pdf and redirect /resume there.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Redirect plugin and redirected /resume to my media content (PDF) URL.

Simple as that. I understand this is a developer forum, but this will help someone some day.